# Java Socket print on Play Framework gets slow in windows

Tags: java, windows, sockets, playframework, thermal-printer

I have a play! framework application that print on a thermal printer using socket with this code :

```
//Command String
String str = "my value passed to this method"    
ObjectOutputStream sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
sOutput.write(str.getBytes());
sOutput.flush();
BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int b;
while ((b = buffer.read()) != -1) {
        //CHECK RESPONSE FOR ERROR
}
```

I call this method for every line I have to print, and I emtpy the response buffer for every row (device comunication protocol requirements).

So, the code works, and it prints without problem, but when I run it on linux (or android, I tested with a little app) it work perfectly fine, but when I run on Windows 10 Pro the print become really slow, almost half a second for line.

I looked around Internet and I tried several things but I can't get my printer to print at a normal speed.

It is a code problem? A network problem?A Windows problem?

Comment: Do you have any details about the printer in question and/or drivers?

Comment: Why `ObjectOutputStream`? Are you recreating the streams for *every* line?

Comment: PiRocks, protocol is just a specification for what to print. Printer is a Cistom II F Ehternet.

Comment: Kayaman, I could also open the stream just one time, but performance doesn't change.

Comment: @Tiz use the `@` to address people, otherwise there won't be notifications. You should open the streams just once anyway, because it's the correct thing to do. You could try to profile it with VisualVM for example, to see what part is slowing down.